# .bat that generates txt file that contains dropped filenames

Tags: batch-file

I want to generate `.abook` files by dropping bunch of files on a `.bat` file. Said file should be named as the folder name of the dropped files.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Audiobook>
  <Header>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Name>###Folder name of dropped files goes here###</Name>
  </Header>
  <FileList>
    <File>###First filename.extension goes here###</File>
    <File>###Second filename.extension goes here###</File>
  </FileList>
</Audiobook>
```

#### Edit:

This Is what I have right now. It is doing what I want but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make it process multiple files.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nx*
echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?^>>%CurrDirName%.abook
echo ^<Audiobook^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
echo   ^<Header^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
echo    ^<Version^>1^</Version^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
echo    ^<Name^>%CurrDirName%^</Name^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
echo   ^</Header^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
echo   ^<FileList^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
FOR %%G IN (%*) DO (
echo    ^<File^>%~nx1^</File^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
)
```

This is the output folderName.abook file when I drag and drop two files (file1, file2)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Audiobook>
  <Header>
   <Version>1</Version>
   <Name>dev</Name>
  </Header>
  <FileList>
   <File>file1.txt</File>
   <File>file1.txt</File>
```

How to make it so it outputs all files not just the first one and repeats that?

Thanks

Comment: If you are new to programming, do yourself a favour and do not start with Windows batch. It is a terrible programming language and largely obsolete by now. Please have a look on e.g. Python or if you for some reason need to use whatever is included with Windows the Powershell.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service! Please read at least the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dragging multiple files on a batch file you get the list of dropped files as a space-separated list. Try this to test

```
@echo %*
@pause
```

Determine the folder name of your dropped file in the set. Something like this

```
for %%* in %* do set CurrDirName=%%~nx*
echo %CurrDirName%
```

echo the first part of the file

```
@echo off
echo ^<?xml version="1.0"?^>^<Audiobook^>^<Header^> ... </FileList>
```

you'll be able to replace the variable in there.

Then do a for loop around the next part of the file, and echo each file extension in the list.

Simple.

FULL FILENAME AND PATH

```
FOR %%G IN (%*) DO (
echo    ^<File^>%%G^</File^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
)
```

EXTENSION ONLY

```
FOR %%G IN (%*) DO (
echo    ^<File^>%%~xG^</File^>>>%CurrDirName%.abook
)
```

Reference

```
Variable with modifier  Description

%~G                     Expands %G which removes any surrounding 
                        quotation marks ("").
%~fG                    Expands %G to a fully qualified path name.
%~dG                    Expands %G to a drive letter only.
%~pG                    Expands %G to a path only.
%~nG                    Expands %G to a file name only.
%~xG                    Expands %G to a file extension only.
%~sG                    Expands path to contain short names only.
%~aG                    Expands %G to the file attributes of file.
%~tG                    Expands %G to the date and time of file.
%~zG                    Expands %G to the size of file.
%~$PATH:G               Searches the directories listed in the PATH environment 
                        variable and expands %G to the fully qualified name of 
                        the first one found. If the environment variable name is 
                        not defined or the file is not found by the search,
                        this modifier expands to the empty string.
```

Comment: Thanks to you I got it started but i'm stuck trying to figure out for loop.
Could you point me in the right direction how to do this for loop part?

Comment: @TõnuRääk I can't read that for toffee. how successful has this been when running so far? Write a little bit, run a little bit. Iterate on it. Google "For loop in batch files"

Comment: Found this http://ss64.com/nt/for.html but my problem is that %~nx* does not work only %~nx1 does.

Comment: @TõnuRääk, the thing is that @Paul used `%%*` as a `for` variable reference, so `%%~nx*` relates to that, it does not relate to the command line arguments `%*`... I strongly recommend to use a different `for` variable reference to avoid such confusion...

Comment: Updated my answer @TõnuRääk

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure you update your answer with the full solution @TõnuRääk